# Boostrap cards - Space between problem!! I need every "eventoCard" to have a space between them

Tags: css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I've been working with Bootstrap 5 and have made something like this before; on each "eventoCard," I need a gutter or space between them; what is happening is that I'm displaying 4 different cards, and they are all stuck up together.

```
<section class="container eventoslist" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-around">
        @foreach ($events->take(4) as $event)
            <div class="eventoCard col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 mb-3 p-0">
                <div class="eventoCardImg">
                    @if (count($event->photos))
                        <img src="{{ asset('storage/event_photos/' .$event->photos()->orderBy('destaque', 'asc')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first()->fotografia) }}"
                             class="img-post" alt="Event image">
                    @else
                        <img src="{{ asset('storage/event_photos/defaultevent.jpg') }}" class="img-post"
                             alt="default image">
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="cardInfo text-center">
                    <h5>{{ $event->name }}</h5>
                    <p class="cardDescription">{{ $event->descricao }}</p>
                    <a href="{{ route('eventoinfo', ['event' => $event]) }}">
                        <button class="btn CardBtn">Saber
                            mais
                        </button>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `gap` utility class in Bootstrap 5, you can add spacing between your Bootstrap cards. This class applies a margin to all sides of an element. Here's how you can modify your code to add a gap between your cards.

```html
<section class="container eventoslist" data-aos="fade-up">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-around gap-3">
        @foreach ($events->take(4) as $event)
            <div class="eventoCard col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 mb-3 p-0">
                <div class="eventoCardImg">
                    @if (count($event->photos))
                        <img src="{{ asset('storage/event_photos/' .$event->photos()->orderBy('destaque', 'asc')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first()->fotografia) }}"
                            class="img-post" alt="Event image">
                    @else
                        <img src="{{ asset('storage/event_photos/defaultevent.jpg') }}" class="img-post"
                            alt="default image">
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="cardInfo text-center">
                    <h5>{{ $event->name }}</h5>
                    <p class="cardDescription">{{ $event->descricao }}</p>
                    <a href="{{ route('eventoinfo', ['event' => $event]) }}"><button class="btn CardBtn">Saber
                            mais</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</section>
```

The `gap-3` class to the `row` div applies a margin of `1rem` (16px) to all sides of each card. You can adjust the number after `gap-` to increase or decrease the spacing. For example, `gap-1` applies a margin of `0.25rem` (4px), `gap-2` applies a margin of `0.5rem` (8px), and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately that did now work for me, instead i gave "m-4" to every card and set them to 20%. That seems to solve my problem for now. I also manage to make it resposive by adding media queries to three diferente screen sizes and the problem is solved.

I will take in consideration using "gap" next time for sure.

Thanks alot.